# Prevent activating the menu by clicking around it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a menu, that by clicking on one of its elements it does an animation and highlight the clicked element, however i noticed that if i click around the menu and not an element, the menu animation is activated. Any help?

JSFIDDLE:  http://jsfiddle.net/kvey3d12/

HTML:

```
 <div id="menu" class="menu">
        <ul class="headlines">
             <li id="item1"><button>aa</button></li>
            <li id="item2"><button>A</button></li>
            <li id="item3"><button>B        </button></li>
            <li id="item4"><button>C         </button></li>
            <li id="item5"><button>D   </button></li>
            <li id="item6"><button>E       </button></li>
            <li id="item7"><button>F       </button></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
li {
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    padding-top: 8px;
    text-align:center;
    border-style: none;
}


.menu li {
    position: relative;
    top: 180px;
    left: 0px;
}
#item7 {
    transition: opacity .8s, left .8s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity .8s, left .8s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .8s, left .8s ease-out;
    -o-transition: opacity .8s, left .8s ease-out;
    margin-left:105px 
}
#item6 {
    transition: opacity 1s, left 1s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s, left 1s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s, left 1s ease-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s, left 1s ease-out;
    margin-left: 95px;
}
#item5 {
    transition: opacity 1.2s, left 1.2s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1.2s, left 1.2s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1.2s, left 1.2s ease-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 1.2s, left 1.2s ease-out;
    margin-left: 60px;
}
#item4 {
    transition: opacity 1.4s, left 1.4s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1.4s, left 1.4s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1.4s, left 1.4s ease-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 1.4s, left 1.4s ease-out;
    margin-left: 123px;
}
#item3 {
    transition: opacity 1.6s, left 1.6s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1.6s, left 1.6s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1.6s, left 1.6s ease-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 1.6s, left 1.6s ease-out;
    margin-left: 113px;
}
#item2 {
    transition: opacity 1.8s, left 1.8s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1.8s, left 1.8s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1.8s, left 1.8s ease-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 1.8s, left 1.8s ease-out;
    margin-left: 130px;
}
#item1 {
    transition: opacity 2s, left 2s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 2s, left 2s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 2s, left 2s ease-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 2s, left 2s ease-out;
    margin-left: 117px;
}

#item1>button{background:none;border:none;outline:none;cursor:pointer;font-size: 1em;}
#item2>button{background:none;border:none;outline:none;cursor:pointer;font-size: 1em;}
#item3>button{background:none;border:none;outline:none;cursor:pointer;font-size: 1em;}
#item4>button{background:none;border:none;outline:none;cursor:pointer;font-size: 1em;}
#item5>button{background:none;border:none;outline:none;cursor:pointer;font-size: 1em;}
#item6>button{background:none;border:none;outline:none;cursor:pointer;font-size: 1em;}
#item7>button{background:none;border:none;outline:none;cursor:pointer;font-size: 1em;}

.permahover li {
    opacity: 1;
    left: -33%;
}
.headlines li {
    font-size:1.5em;
    color:#000000;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.headlines:hover li, .headlines.active li {
    /* PARENT HOVER */
    opacity:0.4;
    cursor: pointer;
    /* Dim all */
}
.headlines li:hover, .headlines li.active {
    /* SINGLE HOVER */
    opacity: 1;
    /* Max one */
    color:#000000;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

JQUERY:

```
$(".menu").on("click", function () {
  $(".menu").addClass('permahover');

});


 var $li = $('.headlines li').click(function() {
    var state = !$(this).hasClass('active');
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('active', state);

    $li.removeClass('active');
    $(this).toggleClass('active', state);
});
```

Comment: Add border or outline to #menu div and you will see where it is. So no wonder that clicking "around" triggers animation.

Comment: @kaaposc but what can it be the solution by keeping the menu current form and location

Comment: Assign "click" to ".menu li", not to whole ".menu": `$(".menu li").on("click", function ()...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this
[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rajkishoreworks/kvey3d12/2/)

```
$("button").on("click", function () {
  $(".menu").addClass('permahover');

});


 var $li = $('.headlines li').click(function() {
    var state = !$(this).hasClass('active');
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('active', state);

    $li.removeClass('active');
    $(this).toggleClass('active', state);
});
```

Comment: finally!! just one thing can this also be applied to the hovering effect, activate and click?

Comment: Is this what you want ? [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rajkishoreworks/kvey3d12/4/) . If not please describe your query a bit more.

Comment: @RJ as V_JOSH_C said i don't want it to show clickable around the menu, or the cursor having any effect on the menu if it's around it.

Comment: @mikeb hopefully! this match to your requirement. [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rajkishoreworks/kvey3d12/5/)

Comment: @RJ man just one thing, the whole menu is in grey.. Any way to return it to black?

Comment: @mikeb if you want the entire thing to be black then what are you going to have the highlight color be ?

Comment: @mikeb [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kvey3d12/8/)   here is a Fiddle of it all being black and highlight color is blue, other than that i dont really know what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

please Check this i think it assure help you
[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kvey3d12/1/)

[demo2](http://jsfiddle.net/kvey3d12/3/)

```
.button{
padding:0;
}
li{
width:22px;
}
```

Comment: no your demo changed the menu location, and still i can click around the menu to activate it